# Use current working directory version of perl module

Tags: perl, module

I am trying to run a perl script and to make it use a module file in the current working directory. I do this because I eventually will need to use the script and module on another machine where I have no control of what or where modules are installed.
My problem is that I can get this to work on some machines, but not others.

The script is:

```
ubuntu@machine-5:/tmp/pig-local$ cat test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w -I ./Text
use Text::CSV_XS ;
print "Hello World\n"
```

and when executed I get the error:

```
ubuntu@machine-5:/tmp/pig-local$ ./test.pl 
Can't locate loadable object for module Text::CSV_XS in @INC (@INC contains: ./Text  ./Text /home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-g
nu-thread-multi /home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/
lib/site_perl .) at ./test.pl line 2
Compilation failed in require at ./test.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./test.pl line 2.
```

The current working directory does have the `Text` directory and the `CSV_XS.pm` module contained in it. I have checked the `md5sum` on the file and it is the same as the machine where the script works.

```
ubuntu@machine-5:/tmp/pig-local$ ls Text/
CSV_XS.pm
```

My OS is:

```
ubuntu@machine-5:/tmp/pig-local$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

and these are the different perl env variables set on the machine:

```
ubuntu@machine-5:/tmp/pig-local$ env | grep -i perl
PERL5LIB=/home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi:/home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5
PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base /home/ubuntu/perl5
PATH=/home/ubuntu/perl5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=/home/ubuntu/perl5
PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/home/ubuntu/perl
```

When I check to see if `perldoc` knows about the module in question,

```
ubuntu@machine-5:/tmp/pig-local$ perldoc -l Text::CSV_XS
./Text/CSV_XS.pm
```

It thinks the module exists in the current working directory.

Any ideas about how to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not properly install the module. It consists of more than a .pm file. It's not the .pm it can't find, it's the .dll/.so that goes with it.

Comment: Where can I find the .so file that goes along with the .pm file?

Comment: You need to build it by properly installing Text::CSV_XS. You can specify which directory want to install it to using passing arguments `PREFIX=~/my_project/perl5 LIB=~/my_project/perl5/lib` to Makefile.PL.

Answer (score 0):

Look:

```
@INC contains: ./Text
```

Guess what is *not* in that directory?  Another directory named "Text".  Hence, perl doesn't find Text::CSV_XS there (it would find just plain CVS_XS tho).

Try `-I .` or:

```
BEGIN { unshift @INC, '.' }
```

Comment: I tried both solutions, and now '.' is in \@INC but still the same error --  ubuntu@hive-slave-5:/tmp/pig-local$ ./test.pl 
Can't locate loadable object for module Text::CSV_XS in @INC (@INC contains: . ./Text  ./Text /home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linu
-gnu-thread-multi /home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/loc
l/lib/site_perl .) at ./test.pl line 5

Comment: @idris I notice the error is actually "can't locate loadable object for module" and not "can't locate module", which implies it has to do with the XS parts. Did you write this module?  If not, *how are you installing it?* Eg: if this was built on one machine and then just zipped up and copied to another machine, and there's a .so in it linked to another lib that isn't there, you might get an error like that -- I use Inline for XS-ish things and so can't say exactly.  In any case "loadable object" would seem to refer specifically to a .so involved and not the module as a whole.